# How to use azure groups as symfony security roles

Tags: symfony, azure-ad-graph-api, symfony6, azure-oauth2

Given roles hierarchy defined in `security.yml` which is used to grant access in our application:

```
role_hierarchy:
  ROLE_COMMERCIAL: [ ROLE_USER ]
  ROLE_MANAGER: [ ROLE_USER ]
  ROLE_COMMERCIAL_ADMIN: [ ROLE_COMMERCIAL ]
  ROLE_MANAGER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_MANAGER ]
  ROLE_ADMIN: [ ROLE_COMMERCIAL_ADMIN, ROLE_MANAGER_ADMIN ]
  ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN ]
```

Now, in azure account, we create some groups and attachs user to their groups.
Example of azure groups:

```
  APP_COMMERCIAL
  APP_MANAGER
  APP_COMMERCIAL_ADMIN
  APP_MANAGER_ADMIN
  APP_ADMIN
  APP_SUPER_ADMIN
```

Now when we connect via azure account using `knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle` and `thenetworg/oauth2-azure`, how to rely on **azure authenticated user groups** and **map** them to **security roles** in symfony?